# Can I use my Arduino nano to upload sketch in Uno's ATmega328p chip?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, arduinoisp

I can not upload sketch to my UNO directly. My ATmega16U2 doesn't work.But the Atmega328P processor still work. 
 I have an arduino nano lying around. Can I use it to upload sketches to Atmega328P directly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can. Either as a USB to UART adaptor and use the Uno's bootloader as you would with any bootloader-enabled breadboard Arduino, or as an Arduino ISP to program the chip directly through the ICSP pins as you would when putting the bootloader onto a blank chip.